# Unexpected behaviour of Kubernetes Job when hitting backoff limit

Tags: kubernetes

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour when a Kubernetes Job hits its backoff limit. This is what appears to happen, based on our logs:

- The Pod fails 6 times (we use the default backoff limit of 6).
- The Pod restarts (for a 7th time).
- Kubernetes kills the Pod a minute or so later.

However, I was not expecting the Pod to start for a 7th time. My expectation is that once the Job's backoff limit is hit the Pod will not be restarted.

Can anyone confirm if this behaviour is expected?